# How to get bean property value from its getter method?

Tags: java, json

I have a json string which contains custom object details as follow.

```
{
    "bankapp.bean.account.CustomerDetails": {
        "setEmail": "value",
        "setCity": "value",
        "setAddress": "value",
        "setBestTime": "value",
        "getBestTime": "value",
        "setPhone": "value",
        "getPassword": "value",
        "getCustomerId": "value",
        "setLastName": "value",
        "getEmail": "value",
        "getLastName": "value",
        "setFirstName": "value",
        "setCustomerId": "value",
        "getPhone": "value",
        "setPassword": "value",
        "getFirstName": "value",
        "getCity": "value",
        "getAddress": "value"
    }
}
```

I want all the properties of this class using its getter methods. Here is the code snippet which i tried but failed.

```
    String jsonString = "{\"bankapp.bean.account.CustomerDetails\":{\"setEmail\":\"value\",\"setCity\":\"value\",\"setAddress\":\"value\",\"setBestTime\":\"value\",\"getBestTime\":\"value\",\"setPhone\":\"value\",\"getPassword\":\"value\",\"getCustomerId\":\"value\",\"setLastName\":\"value\",\"getEmail\":\"value\",\"getLastName\":\"value\",\"setFirstName\":\"value\",\"setCustomerId\":\"value\",\"getPhone\":\"value\",\"setPassword\":\"value\",\"getFirstName\":\"value\",\"getCity\":\"value\",\"getAddress\":\"value\"}}";
JsonObject jObject = new JsonObject(jsonString);
Iterator i = jObject.keys();
while(i.hasNext()) {
    String currentKey = String.valueOf(i.next());
    Object currentValue = jObject.get(currentKey);

    if(currentValue instanceof String) {
        System.out.println("Primitive Object");
    }
    else if(currentValue instanceof JSONObject) {
        //System.out.println("JSON Object");
        String key = getKeyName(jsonString);
        Object jsonObject = jObject.get(key);
        List<String> lList = breakTheJson(jsonObject.toString());
        //List<String> allProperties = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        Iterator<String> iterator = lList.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {                    
                String val = iterator.next();
                if(val.startsWith("get") || val.startsWith("is")){

                    System.out.println(val);

                }

        }

    }
    else if(currentValue instanceof JSONArray) {
        System.out.println("Custom Object");


    }
}
```

So Here in while loop i got values like.

```
getBestTime
getPassword
getCustomerId
getEmail
getLastName
getPhone
getCity
getFirstName
getAddress
```

Now i want to get value like bestTime , password etc. the bean properties.

**Note :** I cant use java reflection because i dont have this class in my classpath. From its getters only i want properties.
Please help me.

Comment: To use the get methods, you will need to have an instance of the object. I think you're actually asking to get the values associated to the getter named keys. Is that right?

Comment: Are you asking for the value (`getBestTime` => "value") or for the attribute name (`getBestTime` => `bestTime`) ?

Comment: @ssssteffff i need bestTime not value. I need property Name only not value

Comment: This is not valid JSON. Always check http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @JordanD sir its a valid json object. I checked already.
Here also i checked http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: ... You can't remove the word "get" and downcase the first letter of what's left?

Comment: @JordanD It's missing the opening '{' - OP probably just missed it by mistake while copying.

Comment: @DaveNewton can you tell me how can i get that ?

Comment: "The JSON Data field does not contain JSON data." is what I get when processing your data, I would recommend fixing the data, validating, then editing your post with a better format.

Comment: @JordanD sorry while copying i missed the first bracket.

Comment: It's basic string manipulation, come on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can you do it simple with Gson

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(Your_String);
//get CustomerDetailsobject
JSONObject jsonObject = json.getJSONObject("bankapp.bean.account.CustomerDetails");
```

Pase with gson

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type typeOf = new TypeToken   <Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();
Map<String,String> map = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), typeOf);

 Set<String> keys = map.keySet();
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (String key : keys) {
         stringBuilder.append(key).append(",");
        }

String str = stringBuilder.toString();
str = str.replaceAll("get", "").replaceAll("set", "");

// also remove the duplicate
LinkedHashSet<String> list = new LinkedHashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(str.split(",")));
for (String property : list) {
    String lowerChar = Character.toString(property.charAt(0)).toLowerCase();
    System.out.println(lowerChar + property.substring(1, property.length()));
    }
```

Your properties

```
email
city
address
bestTime
phone
password
customerId
lastName
firstName
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Then you can do stuff like

CustomerDetails customerDetails = gson.fromJson(jsonString , CustomerDetails .class)

Comment: Yeah but problem is i dont have this class in my classpath. I need property value only not the value.I just need email instead of GetEmail()

Comment: so you are trying to determine the names of the bean properties from the getters?

Comment: Correct.can you please tell me how can i get name

Comment: what Dave Newton suggested is probably the easiest.  Just remove get and downcase the first letter.

Comment: OK fine.. Its comming now :)

Answer (score 0):

To get the property name (ie. `bestTime`) from the getter (ie `getBestTime`), assuming the class complies with the camel case convention, I would simply `substring(3)` and decapitalize the result, using either [Introspector.decapitalize](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html#decapitalize%28java.lang.String%29) (available in the JDK) or [StringUtils.uncapitalize](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#uncapitalize%28java.lang.String%29) (Apache Commons) :

```
if(val.startsWith("get")){
    System.out.println(Introspector.decapitalize(val.substring(3)));
    System.out.println(StringUtils.uncapitalize(val.substring(3)));
} else if(val.startsWith("is")){
    System.out.println(Introspector.decapitalize(val.substring(2)));
    System.out.println(StringUtils.uncapitalize(val.substring(2)));
}
```